# Excel: Get cell color

Tags: excel

1) How do I get the color of a cell using an Excel Macro? I couldn't get this function work:

```
Sub BGCol(MRow As Integer, MCol As Integer)  
bgColor = Cells(MRow, MCol).Interior.ColorIndex  
End Sub
```

2) In the cell x,y I want to have the following formula:

`=BGCol(x,4)`

So how do I get the current row index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a Function:

```
Function BGCol(MRow As Integer, MCol As Integer)  As Integer
   BGCol = Cells(MRow, MCol).Interior.ColorIndex  
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but how can use this in the formula? I want to also get the current row number, such as =BGCol(x,4)

Comment: Use Row() for the row (surprise).

Answer (score 9):

```
Function GetColor(Mycell As Range)

    GetColor = Mycell.Interior.ColorIndex

End Function
```

:::Use Formula::
=getcolor(x4)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you do not want to use Macros or VBA, you can get the **Cell Color** using **Aspose.Cells** API.

**Cell Color** or **Cell Fill Color** is represented by

- Cell>Style>ForegroundColor

**Cell Font Color** is represented by

- Cell>Style>Font>Color

---

**Sample Excel file used inside the Code**

Please consider the following sample Excel file shown inside the snapshot. Here the cell **C4** is filled with **Yellow** color and its font color is **Red**.

[image]

---

The following code in **C#** and **Java** loads the sample Excel file as shown above and accesses the cell C4 and its Style object. Then it prints the cell fill color i.e. **Yellow** and cell font color i.e. **Red**.

Please also see the **Console Output** given below and read the **Comments** inside the code for more understanding.

**C#**

```
// Directory path for input Excel file.
string dirPath = "D:/Download/";

// Load the input Excel file inside workbook object.
Aspose.Cells.Workbook wb = new Workbook(dirPath + "SampleExcelColor.xlsx");

// Access first worksheet.
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

// Access cell C4 by name.
Cell cell = ws.Cells["C4"];

// Access cell style.
Style st = cell.GetStyle();

// Print fill color of the cell i.e. Yellow.
// Please note, Yellow is (R=255, G=255, B=0)
Console.WriteLine(st.ForegroundColor);

// Print font color of the cell i.e. Red.
// Please note, Red is (R=255, G=0, B=0)
Console.WriteLine(st.Font.Color);
```

**Console Output - C#**

```
Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=0]
Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=0]
```

---

**Java**

```
// Directory path for input Excel file.
String dirPath = "D:/Download/";

// Load the input Excel file inside workbook object.
com.aspose.cells.Workbook wb = new Workbook(dirPath + "SampleExcelColor.xlsx");

// Access first worksheet.
Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().get(0);

// Access cell C4 by name.
Cell cell = ws.getCells().get("C4");

// Access cell style.
Style st = cell.getStyle();

// Print fill color of the cell i.e. Yellow.
// Please note, Yellow is (R=255, G=255, B=0)
System.out.println(st.getForegroundColor());

// Print font color of the cell i.e. Red.
// Please note, Red is (R=255, G=0, B=0)
System.out.println(st.getFont().getColor());
```

**Console Output - Java**

```
com.aspose.cells.Color@ffffff00
com.aspose.cells.Color@ffff0000
```