# How to filter Excel cells based on cell interior color?

Tags: colors, filter, excel, vba

I would like to filter rows in big excel sheet - I would like to show only cells which has specific interior color (for example yellow).
Is there any simple way to do it? My idea is writing a VBA function
(something simillar is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110963/excel-get-cell-color) :

```
*public function kolory(komorka as range)
kolory-komorka.interior.color
end function*
```

When I have this function, I am able to generate specific code for each color and then use it to filter it (I can even expand it by adding select case stucture which will translate this code to human readable information).
Unfortunately Excel doesn't see my function (although macros are enabled) and in many situation I am not able to use code written in VB.

Comment: what doesn't work with your function? "Unfortunately Excel doesn't see my function" is not clear enough

Comment: For starters, maybe remove those `*` characters? What are they doing there?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that it doesn't show up in the Macros window? Do you want it to show up as a worksheet function/user defined function? 
If you want to use it as a UDF you need to have a return type and place the code in a regular module. the code would look like

```
public function kolory(komorka as range) as integer
    dim cellColor as integer
    cellColor = komorka.interior.color
    kolory = cellColor
end function
```

If you are trying to use this as a stand alone routine you can't because you require a non-optional input (`komorka as range`). It needs to be called from some containing function/sub that can pass it the `komorka` value. Once you have something that can call your `kolory` function you can use it in your code. The code would look the same as above.

Comment: Of all possible data types, why would you use a `String` to contain color information?

Comment: yes, you're right...bad choice. I changed to integer. better?

Comment: Worse... Try it out and see what happens. For more, see help file on `.Color` and `RGB` function.

Comment: dang. shows me for not having excel in front of me when answering. So is Long best? or is there a dedicated way to store RGB values as RGB and not some equivalent number?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for your function:

```
Public Function kolory(komorka As Range) As Long
    kolory = komorka.Interior.Color
End Function
```

i.e. get rid of those `*` and replace `-` with `=`.

In your Excel sheet, to return the color of cell A1, type `=kolory(A1)` in some other cell.

Of course, if you're just writing VBA code, you don't need function `kolory` since it's just a wrapper for `komorka.Interior.Color`...