# Sum up values based on cell color

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is this possible to sum up all values based on the background color of a cell in excel? I have several cells in red and others in yellow and would like to sum the cell colors separately yet automatically?

Comment: This might help [Processing Coloured Cells](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.ColourCounter.html)

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do this with Excel formulas alone, you need some kind of VBA or other custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to sum only once, or you will be making changes in the spreadsheet and need the new sums?

Are you willing to use macros? Look at http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.ColourCounter.html#summing

Also you can create a function with VBA to get the colors of each cell: 
Function GetColor(Mycell As Range)
    GetColor = Mycell.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10637049/3491999

Then use SUMIF function